# When to use Json over key/value tables in postgres for billions of rows

Tags: json, postgresql, nosql

I am doing a project, where I need to store billions of rows of unstructured history_data in a sql database (postgres) 2-3 years. The data/columns may change from day to day.

So example, day one the user might save {“user_id”:”2223”, “website”:”www.mywebsite.org”, “webpage”:”mysubpageName”}.

And the following day {“name”:”username”, “user_id”: “2223”, “bookclub_id”:”1” }.

I have been doing a project earlier, where we used the classic entity key/value table model for this problem. We saved maybe up to 30 key/values pr entity.   But when exceeding 70-100 mill rows, the queries began to run slower and slower (too many inner joins).

Therefore i am wondering if I should change using the Json model in postgres. After searching the web, and reading blogs, I am really confused. What are the pro and con changing this to json in postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about this in terms of query complexity. If you have an index to the json documents (maybe user_id) you can do a simple index-scan to access the whole json string very fast.

You have to dissect it on the client side then, or you can pass it to functions in postgres, if e.g. you want to extract only data for specific values.

One of the most important features of postgres when dealing with json is having functional indexes. In comparison to "normal" index which index the value of a column, function indexes apply a function to a value of one (or even more) column values and index the return value. I don't know the function that extracts the value of a json string, but consider you want the user that have bookclub_id = 1. You can create an index like

```
create index idx_bookblub_id on mytable using getJsonValue("bookclub_id",mytable.jsonvalue)
```

Afterwards queries like

```
select * from mytable where getJsonValue("bookclub_id",mytable.jsonvalue) = 1
```

are lightning fast.

Comment: Doing indexes on the keys in the Json, I read, that the indexfile size could go through the roof, making the indexfile larger than the db. What I use, would be “simple”, that is no nested files in the Json, but like the examples above and up to 30 key/values pr entity. Is there in that scenario causes to worry about the index size?

Comment: At least in my scenario I don't believe it's a problem. You can always check index sizes in pgAdminIII on the statistics tab of the indexes, so just give it a try and decide for yourself.

Comment: I am not sure but while I type I believe if you use another type of index which indexes ALL key value pairs your might see a large index. This is however not a btree index, but GIS index?!? I don't care if the indexes of my tables exceed the table size by 10x, if the table itself isn't larger than 100mb. The speed gain might be worth it.